# Get int value from each two bytes

Tags: python, byte

I am trying to read bytes from an image, and get all the int (16 bit) values from that image.
After I parsed the image header, I got to the pixel values. The values that I get when the pair of bytes are like b"\xd4\x00" is incorrect. In this case it should be 54272, not 3392.

This are parts of the code:
I use a generator to get the bytes:

```
import itertools

def osddef_generator(in_file):
    with open(in_file, mode='rb') as f:
        dat = f.read()
        for byte in dat:
            yield byte

def take_slice(in_generator, size):
    return ''.join(str(chr(i)) for i in itertools.islice(in_generator, size))

def take_single_pixel(in_generator):
    pix = itertools.islice(in_generator, 2)

    hex_list = [hex(i) for i in pix]
    hex_str = "".join(hex_list)[2:].replace("0x", '')
    intval = int(hex_str, 16)
    print("hex_list: ", hex_list)
    print("hex_str: ", hex_str)
    print("intval: ", intval)
```

After I get the header correctly using the `take_slice` method, I get to the part with the pixel values, where I use the `take_single_pixel` method. 
Here, I get the bad results.
This is what I get:

```
hex_list:  ['0xd4', '0x0']
hex_str:  d40
intval:  3392
```

But the actual sequence of bytes that should be interpreted is: `\xd4\x00`, which equals to `54272`, so that my `hex_list = ['0xd4', '0x00']` and `hex_str = d400`. 
Something happens when I have a sequence of bytes when the second one is `\x00`.

Got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `dat = f.read(); for byte in dat: yield byte` -- this is a bit wasteful. Just do `with open(in_file, 'rb') as f: yield from f`.

Comment: I tried this, and I cannot use iterator.slice() anymore. I always get all the bytes

Comment: That's not the case. You can use `itertools.islice` with any iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are much better ways of converting bytes to integters:

- [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) takes bytes input, and a byte order argument:

  ```
  >>> int.from_bytes(b"\xd4\x00", 'big')
  54272
  >>> int.from_bytes(b"\xd4\x00", 'little')
  212
  ```
- The [`struct.unpack()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) lets you convert a whole series of bytes to integers following a pattern:

  ```
  >>> import struct
  >>> struct.unpack('!4H', b'\xd4\x00\xd4\x00\xd4\x00\xd4\x00')
  (54272, 54272, 54272, 54272)
  ```
- The [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) lets you read binary data representing homogenous integer data into a memory structure efficiently:

  ```
  >>> array.array('H', fileobject)
  ```

  However, `array` can't be told what byte order to use. You'd have to determine the current architecture byte order and call `arr.byteswap()` to reverse order if the machine order doesn't match the file order.

When reading image data, it is almost always preferable to use the `struct` module to do the parsing. You generally then use `file.read()` calls with specific sizes; if the header consists of 10 bytes, use:

```
headerinfo = struct.unpack('<expected header pattern for 10 bytes>', f.read(10))
```

and go from there. For examples, look at the [Pillow / PIL image plugins source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/); here is how the [Blizzard Mipmap image format header is read](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/00f9e8b5f1b0445cac4bdfefb7c9ae9a88f01b0e/src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py#L265-L281):

```
def _read_blp_header(self):
    self._blp_compression, = struct.unpack("<i", self.fp.read(4))


    self._blp_encoding, = struct.unpack("<b", self.fp.read(1))
    self._blp_alpha_depth, = struct.unpack("<b", self.fp.read(1))
    self._blp_alpha_encoding, = struct.unpack("<b", self.fp.read(1))
    self._blp_mips, = struct.unpack("<b", self.fp.read(1))


    self._size = struct.unpack("<II", self.fp.read(8))


    if self.magic == b"BLP1":
        # Only present for BLP1
        self._blp_encoding, = struct.unpack("<i", self.fp.read(4))
        self._blp_subtype, = struct.unpack("<i", self.fp.read(4))


    self._blp_offsets = struct.unpack("<16I", self.fp.read(16 * 4))
    self._blp_lengths = struct.unpack("<16I", self.fp.read(16 * 4))
```

Because `struct.unpack()` always returns tuples, you can assign individual elements in a tuple to `name1, name2, ...` names on the left-hand size, including `single_name, =` assignments to extract a single result.

The separate set of read calls above could also be compressed into fewer calls:

```
comp, enc, adepth, aenc, mips, *size = struct.unpack("<i4b2I", self.fp.read(16))
if self.magic == b"BLP1":
    # Only present for BLP1
    enc, subtype = struct.unpack("<2i", self.fp.read(8))
```

followed by specific attribute assignments.

Comment: This is a lot of suggestions. I will return with my results as soon as I test them. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. It worked using a combination of `struct` methods and `int.from_bytes(sl_pix, 'big')`. :)